# Magento2 import products attribute and attribute sets

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, import, importexport

I'm using Magento 2.1.3.

Is it possible to import product attributes and attribute sets or do I have to create them manually before importing products with specific attributes?

Comment: U have to create from Admin first then u can import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2 product can't be imported if attribute set is absent in system.

You will receive next error after Data Validation:

`Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set doesn't exist?) in row(s): x`

You have to create attribute set manually in Admin Panel or via API request.

See: [Attribute Set REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#!/catalogAttributeSetManagementV1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$eavSetupFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$attributeFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');

$attribute_arr = ['Franciscan Slate','Union Square','Timber Glen','Terrace','Sandalo'];

$attributeInfo= $attributeFactory->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code',['eq'=>"styles_name"])
               ->getFirstItem();
$attribute_id = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();



$option=array();
$option['attribute_id'] = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
foreach($attribute_arr as $key=>$value){
$option['value'][$value][0]=$value;
}



$eavSetup = $eavSetupFactory->create();
$eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create product attributes and attribute sets through admin panel or programatically with M2 module. I don't know way to create product attributes/sets through import.